# Open Local Items Keychain?

Tags: c++, macos, keychain

Does anyone know how to open the Local Items keychain (new in Mavericks) with `SecKeychainOpen`? There are certain entries in that keychain that I'd like to be able to ask the user permission to access using `SecKeychainFindInternetPassword`.

e.g. for the System keychain you call `SecKeychainOpen ("/Library/Keychains/System.keychain",&keychainRef)`.